# Getting Error In Customer to PayPal for Authorization

Tags: php, paypal

I am using **Adaptive Payment Method** for transferring amount from a **PayPal**
account to other PayPal account.

When I am going for pre-approval Authorization with

```
preapprovalKey
PA-7WK619257U8920333
```

(which is I have created by Preapproval API) that time
I am getting an error.

I have tried with Deleted Cache and Delete Cookies.

Please help me and let me know what-what case may be for getting this:

[image]

Comment: If you're using a preapproval key within the Pay request there is no need for any redirection to PayPal.  The use of a preapproval key triggers the transaction immediately without further approval.

Comment: Yes, I agree, But we need to authorize (by a redirect on PayPal standard site as you can see on the screen shot)  that before using that pre-approval key otherwise, you will get an error message for authorizing that pre-approval key.